# WordPress Custom taxonomies filter via 2 dropdowns

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, filter

I have a custom post type called cataloag that I'm using to display posts. There are 2 custom taxonomies associated named yy & mm. I've created 2 dropdowns with the custom taxonomies but would like to be able to select from one or both and change a query to filter on click?

I know that I need the tax_query to bring them together, but creating the function to query on click is beyond me.

I've attached the code I've managed to put together here: http://pastie.org/4121839

Any help will be greatly appreciated.